# how to define a relative bandwidth for the signal with the equation K/w^2

Tags: control-system, fourier

I have a straight line with a slope. Thus its fourier transform is K/w^2. I wanted to estimate its relative bandwidth(Wont it be dependent on the slope?[1st question]).

If the answer for 1st question is yes , the dominant pole is always 0 right?(infinite)
then 99% area or such approximation does not make sense, so how to do such approximation?

Comment: An impulse response with a straight line with a slope (positive slope?) has infinite energy, not exactly describable from the point of view of realizable frequency response. If it's a linear decreasing impulse response, then the Fourier transform is better defined (since the impulse response is zero for negative time and zero when it hits the time axis). Something about your system isn't physical or accurate, what do you mean by "I have a straight line with a slope." Is that your input response?

Comment: positive slope is taken. I wanted to give a line with positive slope into a single pole system with a constant bandwidth. But before that I wanted to find the relative bandwidth of this input @KD9PDP

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, because your input function is non-physical. It's impossible to create a signal that is a straight line with a slope increasing forever, because that requires infinite energy. The bandwidth is also undefined because the value at zero frequency is infinity. Also, the Fourier transform you are showing is for the absolute value of t, not a straight line. The transform you show in unbounded in the time domain for both positive and negative time. So there are so many things wrong with the set up that it makes answering the question impossible.

Comment: oh, okay. Thank you @KD9PDP